# c# code in asp.net for displaying database values in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, html-select

hello everybody im trying to display the database values in my dropdown list, i have created stored procedure for it and trying to get the values by calling that stored procedure in my code behind but im not able to display it. please help me out

```
   protected void DrpClientName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
   {

        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
        {
            objc.ClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
            DataSet ClientN = obj.GetClientList();
            DataView Projview = new DataView();
            Projview.Table = ClientN.Tables[0];
            DrpClientName.DataSource = Projview;
            DrpClientName.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont write the code in dropdowns selected index changed event write it in a function and call it in pageload event

you have to set the DataTextField and DatavalueField

```
objc.ClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
            DataSet ClientN = obj.GetClientList();
            DataView Projview = new DataView();
            Projview.Table = ClientN.Tables[0];
            DrpClientName.DataSource = Projview;
            DrpClientName.DataTextField="Description";
            DrpClientName.DataValueField="ID";
            DrpClientName.DataBind();
```

Comment: thnks mate... its wrkin nw.. by d way i need only textfields... so i removed "id" and its wrking nw :) thnks a ton

Answer (score 1):

you didn't write what you want to display...
you have to use `DisplayMember ValueMember`.

try this:

```
objc.ClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
DataSet ClientN = obj.GetClientList();
DataView Projview = new DataView();
Projview.Table = ClientN.Tables[0];
DrpClientName.DataSource = Projview;
DrpClientName.DisplayMember = "Column name that you want to display";
DrpClientName.ValueMember = "Column name that you want to get the values from";
```

Good luck.

Comment: thnks mate ..its wrking fine nw.. i needed to siplay the client names in my drpdwn which is in database.. well ur code was wrking too but i gt anuj's code fist.. so never mind :)