# access to property on selection winforms combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

One article has `Name` and `Price` properties. I use Name property to display articles inside combobox `cmbDataList` like this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmbDataList.DataSource = GetData();
    cmbDataList.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

After user selected the preffered article I want to use it's `Price` property to assign to textbox on the same form. So, how to access to that `Price` property?

```
private void cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var sel = cmbDataList.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast `SelectedItem` to proper object.

```
private void cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sel = (YourObject)cmbDataList.SelectedItem;
    txt.Text = sel.Price.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless all names are unique, you're going to need a unique identifier to reference, for example an articleID.

From here, set the ComboBox's `ValueMember` like so;

```
cmbDataList.ValueMember = "ID";
```

then you can get your value on the event handler;

```
private void cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sel = cmbDataList.SelectedValue;

    //From here you're going to need to find your article with that particular ID.
}
```

Alternatively. You could have your `DisplayMember` as the article name, and the price as the `ValueMember`, then get it in the event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` in the same way i put above. `SelectedValue` will then return the price;

```
cmbDataList.ValueMember = "Price";

private void cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var yourSelectedPrice = cmbDataList.SelectedValue;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `GetData()` returns a table, you need to write the `ValueMember` also... like this:

```
InitializeComponent();
    cmbDataList.DataSource = GetData();
    cmbDataList.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbDataList.ValueMember = "Price";
```

Now, your selected display will be synced with the value and you will be able to use it..

Get more info in here:
 [Populate combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184599/c-sharp-code-in-asp-net-for-displaying-database-values-in-dropdown-list/17184817#17184817)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to set ValueMember You can set in this way

**cmbDataList.ValueMember = "ID";**

then you write the code on cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged Event

May be this will help you

**var sel = cmbDataList.SelectedValue**